# XML de-serialization of an array

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have such an xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<response>
    <id-number>2979183</id-number>
    <differentiator-question>
        <prompt>How old are you?</prompt>
        <type>age.range</type>
        <answer>29 - 38</answer>
        <answer>39 - 48</answer>
        <answer>49 - 58</answer>
        <answer>59 - 68</answer>
        <answer>None of the above</answer>
    </differentiator-question>
    <error>Invalid username and password</error>
</response>
```

which I try to de-serialize using the built in serialization mechanism in .NET.
Created such a class

```
[XmlRoot("response")]
public class IdologyAnswerMapping
{
    [XmlElement("id-number")]
    public string IdNumber { get; set; }    
    public class DifferentiatorQuestionType
    {
        [XmlElement("prompt")]
        public string Prompt { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("type")]
        public string Type { get; set; }

        [XmlArray("answer")]
        public string[] Answers { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlElement("differentiator-question")]
    public DifferentiatorQuestionType DifferentiatorQuestion { get; set; }

    public static IdologyAnswerMapping FromXml(string xml)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(IdologyAnswerMapping));
        IdologyAnswerMapping answer = (IdologyAnswerMapping)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xml));
        return answer;
    }
}
```

But the Answers array is of zero size. How do I place all the `<answer />` tags into Answers array?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `XmlElement` instead of `XmlArray`

```
[XmlElement("answer")]
public string[] Answers { get; set; }
```